# Where did the VScode rebuild container command go?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

The recent update on VScode made this option disappear. How do I rebuild the container when running the dev container?

[image]

Answer (score 15):

In the primary sidebar: click on "Remote Explorer", then right click on the Dev container you want to rebuild, there you'll find the "Rebuild Container" option.

Comment: wow, thank you. This is not obvious at all!

Comment: For this work for me the container had to run.

Answer (score 3):

There are two commands that rebuild the image.

- When running vscode inside the container: `Dev Containers: Rebuild Container` and `Rebuild Container Without Cache`
- When not in the container: `Dev Containers: Rebuild and Reopen in Container`  and `Rebuild Without Cache and Reopen in Container`

[Source](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/create-dev-container#_rebuild)

Answer (score -1):

Please note:

1. If the container won't build, the container won't run, so get the container built and working first before loading it using devcontainers.
2. If you make a breaking change, again you have to go back to the original folder until the build is fixed.
3. If someone sets the devcontainer.json to `"image": "some_image_name"` then rebuild container command will always use that, so the command gets downgraded to "reload the existing container", so make sure image is not set but dockerFile is.